# Phonegap jQuery onClick handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am trying to open links with the default ios system browser instead of the inappbroswer plugin. The following code does not open with the system browser:

```
function openlink(x){
window.open(x.href, "_system");
return false;
}

<h1><a href="http://google.com" class="exLink">google</a></h1>
<h1><a href="http://yahoo.com" class="exLink">yahoo</a></h1>

$("html").click(function(){
$(".exLink").attr("onclick", "javascript:return openlink(this)");
});
```

This code does open with the system browser but it's not what I need.

```
<h1><a href="http://google.com" onClick='javascript:return openlink(this)'>google</a></h1>
```

What's the best way to get the onclick attr() to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(".exLink").on('click', function() { openlink(this); return false; });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the click event for the .exLink is assigned, but not triggered, only when html level is clicked.

unless capturing the click event at the html level is there for a reason, try

```
$(function(){
  $(".exLink").attr("onclick", "javascript:return openlink(this)");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simple like this -

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://google.com', '_system');">google</a>
```